# C++ how to link ffmpeg with cmake on windows

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I have downloaded ffmpeg dev files from [ffmpeg.zeranoe.com](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) and succesfully included the headers in my application. However, I am getting undefined errors when linking.

```
undefined reference to `avformat_open_input(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, AVDictionary**)'
```

I am using a [FindFFMEG.cmake](https://github.com/robotology/ycm/blob/master/find-modules/FindFFMPEG.cmake) file to find ffmpeg library. From the cmake cache I see that it finds the library:

```
FFMPEG_avcodec_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/Users/User/Google Drive/workspace/C++/Project/Dependencies/ffmpeg/lib/libavcodec.dll.a
...
```

This is how I am linking:

```
find_package(FFMPEG REQUIRED)
if (FFMPEG_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${FFMPEG_LIBRARIES})
    include_directories(${FFMPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif (FFMPEG_FOUND)
```

I guess I am missing some files that should be included?

How can I link ffmpeg correcly in my c++ project with cmake?

Edit:
I am using mingw64